# compileTestJava failing after gradle upgrade

Tags: java, gradle, jenkins

The history of the issue is that everything used to work fine before upgrading to gradle 8 and then it started to fail with:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSClassUnloadingEnabled'
Error: Could not create the java virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occured
```

I removed that variable and then my test cases fail with the following type of issue:

```
/workersfsPODB45/workspace/kenkins-build45/-1021654004/44/src/test/java/com/wellsfargo/ccbs/bizmanagers/PricingManagerTest.java:109: error: cannot find symbol private RequestInfo requestInfo;
```

`RequestInfo` comes from the JDK:

```
org.omg.PortableInterceptor
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: What's the code? What upgrades did you perform?

Answer (score 0):

Package `org.omg.PortableInterceptor` was part of the `java.corba` module which was removed in JDK 11 because of https://openjdk.org/jeps/320. It seems that you upgraded the JDK version probably from JDK 8 or earlier to JDK 11 or later. You should search for alternative implementations of CORBA for Java if you need it.

Note that the previous error about JVM argument `-CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` is unrelated to this issue.

Comment: I am still using JDK8. Can there be versions of JDK8 that removed this module?

Comment: Which exact version of JDK 8?